# When I update my data with PHP CodeIgniter, It gives an error. But data is saving

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, undefined, fatal-error

I am using 'CodeIgniter-3.1.3'. When I update my data, it gives an error as follow. But my data is saving in database. I can't find what is the issue. Is there any issue with my model function related to version..?

> `Error : Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::_error_number()`

**In Controller**

```
public function saveUpdateData(){
    $updateDataArray = array(
        "fname" => $_POST['fname'],
        "lname" => $_POST['lname'],
        "username" => $_POST['user'],
        "userlevel" => $_POST['userlevel'],
        "contact" => $_POST['contact_no']
    );
    $whereArr=array("user_id"=>$this->input->post("user_id"));
    $rst = $this->MyModel->updateData("admin", $updateDataArray, $whereArr);

    if ($rst) {
      echo "updated";
    }    
    else{
      echo "error";
    }
}
```

**In model**

```
function updateData($tablename, $data_arr, $where_arr) {
    try {
        $this->db->update($tablename, $data_arr, $where_arr);
        $report = array();
        $report['error'] = $this->db->_error_number();
        $report['message'] = $this->db->_error_message();
        return $report;
    } catch (Exception $err) {
        return $err->getMessage();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WTUe.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

**In Model**

```
function updateData($tablename, $data_arr, $where_arr) 
{
    if (!$this->db->update($tablename, $data_arr, $where_arr)) {
        $result = $this->db->error(); 
    } 
    else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
$rst = $this->MyModel->updateData("admin", $updateDataArray, $whereArr);

if ($rst == TRUE) {
  echo "updated";
}    
else{
  print_r($rst);
}
```

---

Read [Error Handling Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#handling-errors)

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

In CodeIgniter 3+, you can get errors with error no and messages as by using the following:
`$error = $this->db->error();`

Reference: [Handling Query Errors in CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#handling-errors)

Answer (score 0):

The functions you are trying to access have been deprecated.

Replace:

- `$this->db->_error_number()`
- `$this->db->_error_message()`

With:

- `$this->db->error()`

The new function will return an array with both the error number and message.

Refer to this CodeIgniter page:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html?highlight=_error_number